# What do you call the fastener that's like a metal zip tie with a screw?

Tags: fastener

I assure you that this is not the beginning of a fastener-related standup routine.

While working out at the gym, I saw a fastener that looks like a metal zip tie, with a screw to tighten it. Two pictures below. This can be useful for me in some of my projects. Any idea what it's called and where I can buy it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I generally say something along the lines of "spiral hose clamp".

Comment: Damn, I wanted to hear the end of that joke!

Comment: Just don't call it "late for dinner"!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This particular type is a band hose clamp, worm screw, stainless steel. In Britain a [Jubilee clip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jubilee_Clip).

[316 stainless steel worm gear hose clamp Grainger](https://www.grainger.com/category/worm-gear-clamps/hose-clamps/pneumatics/ecatalog/N-afyZ1yzaq05?gclid=Cj0KCQjwvezZBRDkARIsADKQyPma3wxJbmdYb2r3sE83BtgCeyGyZlL_kitPCAJ3uBus7KcL3Inqd8MaApgWEALw_wcB&cm_mmc=PPC:%20Google%20Main%201-_-Dynamic%20Search%20Ads-_-Plumbing-_-&adgrpID=4658246543&kwdID=&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!239675950239!b!!g!!&ef_id=Wb6hZAAABW5VfXMN:20180703095208:s)

Comment: I've also heard "[Worm drive clamp](https://www.mcmaster.com/#worm-drives/=1dl0c61)"

Comment: Worm gear clamps. https://www.grainger.com/search/pipe-hose-tube-fittings/hose-products/hose-accessories/worm-gear-clamps?tv_optin=true&searchQuery=hose+clamps&searchBar=true

Answer (score 54):

It's a hose clamp.  Any hardware or automotive store carries them in the US.

Comment: OP, **hose clamp** is the right answer, as [Google Images verifies](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=hose%20clamp&tbs=imgo:1).

Comment: @user1717828: Google image is not smart enough to store multiple names for the  same thing, it just takes the majority i.e. American English. in British English: 'jubilee clip'

Comment: @user1717828 Your link is evidence that it is **a** correct answer, but nothing to establish that it is **the** correct answer.

Answer (score 16):

Another common name for this type hose clamp is "gear clamp". They come in a variety of sizes to accommodate various hose diameters.

[image]

<sub>*(Image from [PrecisionBrand.com](https://precisionbrand.com/products/hd6s-916-band-heavy-duty-3-piece-stainless-worm-gear-hose-clamp-38-78-clamping-diameter-pack-of-10/).)*</sub>

Comment: And, lacking a large size, one can link several smaller clamps together to form one large clamp...

Answer (score 2):

In the US, they are called '**hose clamps**', though if you goto an automotive parts store, they will likely call them '**radiator clamps**' as that was their primary use in automotive work, fastening the hoses to the radiator.

Answer (score 1):

It's called "abrazadera" in Argentina.
It's a valid answer, just for the more you know.

Comment: This sure will come in handy if I'm ever in Argentina and need to do a plumbing repair.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Doesn't that just mean "clamp"? I think the OP was looking for something more specific.

Comment: There are a lot of very different products that go by abrazadera.

Comment: Magical plumbers call it abracadabra.

Answer (score 0):

In professional residential environments, I always heard these called a "duct clamp" or "duct cinch." But I always see them labeled (in US Home Depot) as hose clamps, as the other answers have stated. I think the former terms are more like slang

Comment: I'm guessing that's mostly residential?  I don't recall seeing these clamps much in commercial ventilation or electrical systems.

Comment: @JMac correct. I work for a construction company that builds single family homes. The guys I work under call them duct clamps  most often. I'll edit to clarify.